# Catching a WPF implicit conversion error

Tags: validation, exception, binding

I have a WPF TextBox that is bound to an integer property. If I enter any letters in the textbox, the textbox diaplays a red border whenit loses focus, indicating a conversion error. So far so good.

I want to trap the conversion error in code. I was thinking that the error came from a conversion exception, and that an ExceptionValidationRule on the textbox binding object would fail validation in these cases. However, this seems not to be the case.

In the following example, I would have expexted the background to turn orange when a text string is entered and I click the button, but this doesn't happen.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ValidationTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:ValidationTest="clr-namespace:ValidationTest" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="89" Width="239">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" >
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="IntegerField">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <ExceptionValidationRule />
                    <!--ValidationTest:IntegerValidationRule /-->
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    <Button Content="Test" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="146,12,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" Click="button1_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ValidationTest {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public int IntegerField { get; set; }

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) {
            // Validate all the bindings on the textbox 
            bool valid = true;
            LocalValueEnumerator localValues = textBox1.GetLocalValueEnumerator();
            while (localValues.MoveNext()) {
                LocalValueEntry entry = localValues.Current;
                if (BindingOperations.IsDataBound(textBox1, entry.Property)) {
                    Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(textBox1, entry.Property);
                    foreach (ValidationRule rule in binding.ValidationRules) {
                        ValidationResult result = rule.Validate(textBox1.GetValue(entry.Property), null);
                        if (!result.IsValid) {
                            valid = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            this.Background = valid ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.Orange;
        }

    }

    public class IntegerValidationRule : ValidationRule {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo) {
            int val;
            if (!int.TryParse(value as string, out val)) {
                return new ValidationResult(false, "NAN");
            }
            return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        }
    }
}
```

I can achieve the desired functionality in the example by uncommenting the custom IntegerValidationRule in XAML... but this is not applicable in my "real" app because the datatypes the text boxes binds to is not known at design time.

Does anybody know a solution to this?